# sending request to named route with parameters

Tags: laravel, vue.js, request, inertiajs

I'm trying to send request to laravel named route `users.update` with parameter `user`:

```
const saveUser = () => {
    router.put(route("users.update", user.value.id), user.value);
    submitted.value = true;
    createUserDialog.value = false;
    user.value = {};
    toast.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Successful",
        detail: "User Updated",
        life: 3000,
    });
};
```

`user.value` is an object ref that contains users information to update, it looks like this:

```
{studentNumber: "142", id: 49, email: "ahickle@example.net" ...etc}
```

now it accepts parameter `user`, but the request is actually ignored by the controller method, it looks like the request gets redirected to the same page:

```
    public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, User $user) : RedirectResponse
     {
        $user->update($request->validated());

        if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
            $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
        }


        return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard');

    }
```

`web.php`

```
Route::Resource('users', UserController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

I tried to `dd($request)` or send back `$request` as `json`, but there is no response, in the network tab, the request headers shows status code `303 See Other`, the response says that `no content is available because the request was redirected`, but it doesn't actually redirects to `admin.dashboard`, if it really redirects then it redirects to the same page, what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Do you see in the network tab of the browser showing the request being passed to correct route with the right parameters?

Comment: it hangs hangs  then it returns status code ```303 : see other```, and then redirects to same page

Comment: I see. When you log the statement `console.log(route('users.update'))`. Does it return the correct route?

Comment: when i log ```console.log(route("users.update", { user: user.value }));```, it returns ```http://localhost/users/8``` or whatever the id is

Comment: You need to pass user.value to the put method, `router.put('http://localhost/users/8', user.value)`

Comment: yeah, its the request payload, but the problem is not actually missing paylaod, it is that the request is getting redirected to the same page, and that's the only thing that happens

Answer (score 0):

```php
Route::put('/api/user/{user}')->name('users.update');
```

```php
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, User $user) {}
```

```js
const saveUser = () => {
    // router.put(url, data, options)
    router.put(
        // parameter passed to the route helper is used for the url
        route("users.update", user.value.id),
        // we pass our data as the 2nd argument
        user.value
    );
    submitted.value = true;
    createUserDialog.value = false;
    user.value = {};
    toast.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Successful",
        detail: "User Updated",
        life: 3000,
    });
};
```

For use on the `route()` helper: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy?tab=readme-ov-file#parameters 
Requests with `router` https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits

Comment: the request was indeed missing payload, now it has payload of user object with data, but still the same problem, request gives status code ```303 See Other```

Comment: i also tried to do it Inertia way like this : ```router.put(`users/${user.value.id}`, user.value);```, but didn't work, same status code

Comment: 303 is a redirect, what response are you returning from the controller? it can also be a middleware returning a redirect response (auth?). controller should check if request wants json or not before redirecting and only redirect browser requests

Comment: i put my controller update method in the post, yeah im using auth middleware, but as shown in the controller code, im not redirecting the request

Comment: `return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard');` this is a redirect and your return type is `RedirectResponse`. you can return an array, JsonResponse, status 204 or whatever

Comment: i keep updating my post